# Dragdrop from treeview to panel or other control in wpf using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drag-and-drop, treeview

I need to drag and drop the content from a treeview to a panel or group box where it needs to looks like below image
[image]

For each item which i drag from treeview and drop it into the panel must create a 
box like this [image: this] and get added into that place holder..**Is it possible in wpf c#?**If so any tutorial available.? I am really new to wpf . I checked on telerik and there doesn't seems any functionality like this..

Comment: You could take a look at gong/wpf drag drop: https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop  which should give you a head start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Drag from tree and drop to panel. Example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859(v=vs.100).aspx)

When drop event handler rises you should create box Control and add to panel